# Nginx rewrite url because https doesn't work

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I for some reason am tasked with doing a url rewrite from HTTPS to HTTP.

Background: I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy and need to have the location block in the 443 block while the application gives mixed resource errors and doesn't work on HTTPS (so the dev says).

What I want to get: I want it so that the Nginx location block is in the 44 server block but all traffic is done over HTTP (80).

Anyone know how to do this? I was thinking a URL rewrite.

And yes I know it would make more sense to put it in the port 80 server block compared to 443. Seniors have weird ideas some days.

**Location block**

```
location /solution_tools/ {
   auth_basic "Please enter your credentials";
   auth_basic_user_file solutions_utils.pass;
   proxy_pass http://solution_tools/;
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps post a copy of your config

Comment: @Drifter104 I would but it is in a chef cookbook and is close to 2000 lines. Way too much to post here and stripping it down to the important parts would take a long time also because there is a lot of if statements that sometimes exist and others don't and explaining them and figuring out what ones are going to be there on the node I am building takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

> *"the application gives mixed resource errors and doesn't work on HTTPS (so the dev says)"*

Then the developer should fix the app because this day and age any web app that won't support HTTPS is completely deprecated.

If the app can't be fixed then rather than redirect back to plain HTTP do the opposite, use the fact that you are already running a reverse proxy to the max benefit and rewrite the "faulty" html code that refers to absolute URL's over plain http  `http://www.exameple.com/` to https `httpS://www.exameple.com/` and fix the mixed content issue that way.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html:

```
location / {
    sub_filter 'http://$host/'  '"https://$host/';
    sub_filter_once on;
}
```

Comment: Oh I agree they should fix it but that is not up to me to decide. I can only voice my opinion and let others handle it. It is an internal tool so guess that is why they are not too worried.

I will try those Nginx changes. Far as I am told nothing will be using HTTPS for this but maybe enough talking and explaining might change it. The DevOps team want HTTPS but the lone dev on his own team with no boss thinks its just fine.

Comment: I added that to my location block and it failed to reload the service. I have posted my location block as is in the OP.

Comment: From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) : 
*"This module is **not built by default**, it should be enabled with the `-with-http_sub_module` configuration parameter."*